# single signon + spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on

Can anybody tell me how to implement single signon in my spring application.(Tomcat or Jboss server)

share me any documentation or link to bring this feature in my spring app.

I am using spring 2.5.6 .

Pls do the needful.

Comment: I would very much enjoy doing the needful for you :)

Comment: The needful is for _you_ to get reading. Be aware that you need to understand what security does for you in order to use it correctly.

Answer (score 10):

What you need is [spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

It supports both [OpenID](http://openid.net/) and [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) out of the box, but you'll need to do some research on your own on those.

If you need just basic SSO functionality I can recommend just implementing your own `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and/or `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and using cookies. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232683/using-spring-security-3-with-cookies/6275804#6275804) answer will help you do that.

You also should have a look at the [spring-security docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html) and then ask a more specific question if you need to.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd call using username/password a single-signon feature; there's no sharing of the credentials with other sites. OpenID and CAS most certainly fit the bill though.

Comment: @Donal I have currently implemented basic SSO with a custom UserPassAuthFilter and a custom UserDetailsService within a current project of mine using cookies and it seems very nice so far. I'll make a blog post about it at some point.

Comment: As long as the sites all share the same domain then cookies are certainly a viable option with with some customization.

Comment: If you use just cookies however implementing the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` should probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CAS *(Central Authentication Service)*

http://www.jasig.org/cas

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an out of the box solution [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com) could be a good option as it includes single sign on, user management and two factor authentication. There is a dedicated [Spring client](http://www.cloudseal.com/spring-extension) available for the platform

N.B. I work for Cloudseal so I'm biased!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider Kerberos. Below is a detailed Javadoc on the same --

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jgss/single-signon.html