# How to disable spring application login security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I like to call Joget workflow web application (having spring based security) URL from my another web application. But I do not want to show login page to users. basically it should allow user to directly enter inside the application without login authentication.

Or How to do Single Sign on from my webapps to Joget (spring based apps) workflow application.

Joget application is using "j_spring_security_check" for user authentications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Single Sign On scenario.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340466/single-signon-spring/6340625#6340625) might help you with that.