# Spring Security Performances

Tags: performance, spring, spring-security, scalability

My web app is using Spring Security 3 as login manager and users data (username, password, etc) are saved on database.
Now we added external applications that are supposed to use the same login page internally to the first app. That could be a problem especially for performance reasons. Is it possible take out the "spring security part" as a separate module? How can I keep in this case the redirection working in the main application? Design suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need a [Single Sign On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) concept implemented.

Spring security supports two of those out of the box. You could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340466/single-signon-spring/6340625#6340625) answer for details.

Comment: Yes I think you are right thanks. For Spring Security maybe JA-SIG  as CAS server is a good choice?

Comment: @Randomize IMO Jasig is the most mature one.